# Efficient way to get previous n day by date data from LINQ/EF

Tags: c#, performance, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a Sales tables that holds all order details. It has columns ID, SaleDate, Price. Through Entity Framework v4, what is the efficient way to get day by day total sales for previous 30 days?

```
public static List<ChartTotal> GetTotalsByDate()
{
    List<ChartTotal> totals = new List<ChartTotal>();
    ChartTotal totalForDay = null;
    DateTime orderDate = DateTime.Now;
    int DAY_COUNT = 30;
    using (LinqModel db = new LinqModel())
    {
        do
        {
        DAY_COUNT--;
        orderDate = orderDate.AddDays(-1);
        totalForDay = new ChartTotal { OrderDate = String.Format("{0:dd MMM}", orderDate), Total = db.Sales.Where(p=>p.SaleDate < orderDate).Sum(o => o.GrandTotal) };
        totals.Add(totalForDay);
        } while (DAY_COUNT > 0);
    }
    return totals;
}
```

I dont want it to be done so crude. Can I somehow get all the data in one go, in other words, I would like to replace the loop so I could minimize the round trips. Should I go for stored procedure instead?

Environment: Asp.Net 4.5, EF v4, SQL Sever 2012, VS 2012.

Comment: Does `SaleDate` include a time, or just a date?

Comment: Includes both date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the every day total for the last 30 days (including today). You can use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` to strip the timepart of the `DateTime`.

```
var q = from x in Sales
        where x.SaleDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) &&
              x.SaleDate <= DateTime.Now
        group x by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.SaleDate) into g
        select new ChartTotal()
        {
           OrderDate = g.Key,
           Total     = g.Sum(y => y.GrandTotal)
        };
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Had to use this too `EntityFunctions.AddDays(DateTime.Now, -30)`

Comment: The class `EntityFunctions` has been replaced with `DbFunctions`